# Flask classful giving 404 error for minimal app

Tags: python, flask

I am going through this document: https://flask-classful.teracy.org/

Copied minimal app from above document.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_classful import FlaskView

# we'll make a list to hold some quotes for our app
quotes = [
    "A noble spirit embiggens the smallest man! ~ Jebediah Springfield",
    "If there is a way to do it better... find it. ~ Thomas Edison",
    "No one knows what he can do till he tries. ~ Publilius Syrus"
]

app = Flask(__name__)

class QuotesView(FlaskView):
    @app.route("/")
    def index(self):
        return "<br>".join(quotes)

QuotesView.register(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

While I am running this app, it is giving 404 error.

```
(venv) C:\fifa\web_app_flask_bootstrap>python app.py
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2022 13:44:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I am having following flask related packages installed:

```
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-Classful==0.14.2
Python version: 3.9.2
```

What could be the reason for showing that error?

Trial1:
Changed port and tried. `app.run(port=5001)` Getting same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to provide `route_base='/'` on `QuotesView` class?

Comment: @Ingwar Modified question by adding that line too. Same error.

Comment: okay, so - try to start python in env, import app and list app route rules. Maybe somehow your endpoint not registered at all, or there is different route path

Comment: Run the app in debug mode with `app.run(debug=True)`, it may give to you a more detailed error message.

Comment: @Ingwar yes.. you are correct. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @LinkOut: Detailed error is: `The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Comment: What exactly I was correct about? Route not registered, or it has different path? If it has other endpoint - try to put `route_base` at the first. Maybe @LinkOut was right in his thoughts, and it build endpoint path with class name, if `route_base` was not provided - at first look on source of flask-classful i can't find something about it.
And don't use `@app.route` - you need to use classful route - `from flask_classful import route` (as i can see in the docs)

Answer (score 1):

Change this 2 lines to:

`@app.route("/")` to `@route("/")`

`QuotesView.register(app)` to

```
QuotesView.register(app, route_base='/')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet in the link that you provided doesn't include the decorator `@app.route('/')` before the `index` function. And, immediately after the snippet, it say: `Run this app and open your web browser to: http://localhost:5000/quotes/`.

I don't know how `Flask-Classful` works but I guess that it takes the name of the class and use it as endpoint (in this example, `QuotesView`, take all before `View` and make it lowercase). But, again, it's a guess.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).